# How to change variable value in Svelte app via browser's console

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

Could you please explain how can I see reactivity in Svelte app. So if I change variable value in browser's console I would see updated DOM.
If I have App.svelte file below, is it possible to assign new value to "name" variable in browser's console and see update "h1" element instantly?

```
<script>
let name = 'world';
</script>

<h1>Hello world!</h1>

<h1>Hello {name}!</h1>
```

Comment: What did you try and what was the result?

Comment: I've tried to assign new value directly and tried to search how can I achieve it but that didn't work. So I thought there is a specific way to do that.

Comment: Try the chome extension called svelte devtools. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/svelte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not directly possible with Svelte.  The reason for this is because those variables do not exists on the global scope of your document, they are encapsulated by the browser into the app and shielded from outside interference.

One way around this would be to explicitly define a way to do this

```html
<script>
    let name = 'world';
    
    window.setName = (val) => name = val;
</script>

<h1>Hello {name}!</h1>
```

Now you can do `window.setName('test')` in the console and it will change the value of `name`

Comment: Thanks, that explains and covers my question.

Answer (score 1):

Svelte compiles your code, so it's not possible to get variables from the browser console. This also means that you cannot use Svelte from a CDN, i.e. `<script src="//cdn/svelte.min.js">` is not valid.

However, if you need to check reactivity, you could update the variable value on (say) a button click.

```
<script>
    let message = 'Hello';
</script>

<button on:click={() => { message = 'Bye bye' }}>
    Change content
</button>
<h1>
    >>> {message}
</h1>
```

Or follow this snippet from the docs - https://svelte.dev/tutorial/text-inputs

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this is via proxies or using the Object.defineProperties function on window.

For example, lets say you have a variable called "name".

```js
Object.defineProperty(window, "name", {
    get: function() {
      return name
    },

    set: function(val) {
      name = val
    }
})
```

This actually seems to work quite well as all you have to do is update the variable normally and it will reflect.